# EasyPG passphrase confirmation

Tags: emacs, gnupg

I keep secrets in a GPG passphrase-encrypted file, which I access through Emacs/EasyPG.

This works fine, but when I change the file and write it, I have to enter the passphrase twice (once extra for confirmation).

One would think that the confirmation can be skipped if the new passphrase is the same as the original passphrase.
Is this something EasyPG supports?
Or, how could I achieve this in elisp?

Environment:

- GNU Emacs 29.1
- MacOS Ventura 13.4.1
- GnuPG 2.4.3
- `ps` gives `gpg-agent --homedir /Users/.../.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon`

EasyPG customizations that to tell Emacs where to find `gpg` let me enter credentials in the minibuffer:

```
 '(epg-gpg-program "/opt/homebrew/opt/gnupg@2.2/bin/gpg")
 '(epg-pinentry-mode 'loopback)
```

`.gnupg/gpg.conf`:

```
auto-key-retrieve
no-emit-version
```

`.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned my environment (added now).
Yes, I am running `gpg-agent`.

Comment: Do you customize `epg` behavior in `Emacs` in any way? Do you enter pass in minibuffer or macOS interface?  I use [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/68304/28451), (currently without adding lines to `gpg-agent.conf`) and enter the pass once. [I didn't try Emacs 29 yet though.]

Comment: Yes, I have two customisations (added above), which seem the same as the ones you refer to (I also have not added to `gpg-agent.conf`). I enter my password in the minibuffer.